# borg backup hangs on most commands after verified integrity

Tags: linux, backup, borgbackup

I have a borg backup system for some time now. The target is cloud storage, accessed by ssh.

This is SSH command line from debug:

```
SSH command line: ['ssh', '-i', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa', '-p', '23', '<censored>@<censored>.your-storagebox.de', 'borg', 'serve', '--umask=077', '--debug']
```

The cloud storage was full and it caused a `borg prune` command to stop responding.

In the meantime I have killed the process for that command, deleted the borg cache, and have broken the lock.

If I try to run `borg info` or `borg check`, the command stops after
`Remote: Verified integrity of /home/backup/hints.8441`

Here is the output of the debug:

```
borg check --debug <repo>
using builtin fallback logging configuration
35 self tests completed in 0.36 seconds
SSH command line: ['ssh', '-i', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa', '-p', '23', '<censored>@<censored>.your-storagebox.de', 'borg', 'serve', '--umask=077', '--debug']
Remote: using builtin fallback logging configuration
Remote: 33 self tests completed in 0.08 seconds
Remote: using builtin fallback logging configuration
Remote: Initialized logging system for JSON-based protocol
Remote: Resolving repository path b'/./backup'
Remote: Resolved repository path to '/home/backup'
Remote: Starting repository check
Remote: Verified integrity of /home/backup/index.8441
Remote: Verified integrity of /home/backup/hints.8441
```

After that, the borg hangs (I have waited for a few hours now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Again, it turns out, server management requires patience. A couple of hours later, the check is complete and found no issues.

Now everything works much faster. `borg info` takes only few seconds. I guess all data needed is now in cache. (Cache is 2.15GB).